# broken preg_match function ? (php 7.4.2)

Tags: php, preg-match, php-7.4

I have a very strange problem.

When I open the script below in the browser and execute it, everything works as expected. Even if I call the script in the command line, I have the expected result.

But if I run the script in a background job, the script aborts in the "preg_match" function without any error. I don't have an error message for this anywhere, neither in the logs nor anywhere else. I also checked if the function exists and it does.

The script just seems to abort at preg_match and doesn't show any message about possible errors. So i'm getting only the output "CHECKPOINT 1".

I have checked the PHP versions and everywhere the same version (same path). Also the settings of pcre are identical.

Is it possible that I have different modules or functions for preg_match? Is there any way I can check what happens in the function?

with try & catch i don't get any information about the problem.

```
<?php
class pcre_check
{

    public function setUp() {
    }

    public function perform() {

      echo "CHECKPOINT 1";
      preg_match("/[0-9]{4}/", "6876 ABCDEFGH", $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
      print_r($matches);
          echo "CHECKPOINT 2";
    }

    public function tearDown() {

    }
}

$test   = new pcre_check();
$test->setUp();
$test->perform();
$test->tearDown();
?>
```

Systeminfos:

- Apache server
- PHP 7.4.2

The same script works online on the production server. Only on my local server I have this problem.

**It seems there is an issue with regular expressions. The function preg_replace isn't working too but str_replace with replacement of a normal string is working.**

Comment: How are you capturing the output from your background job? What type of background job is it (e.g. crontab)? What's the point of calling the `setUp()` and `tearDown()` functions if they're empty?

Comment: Do you have error reporting set on E_ALL and php ini display_errors on ?

Comment: the background script is php-resque (https://github.com/resque/php-resque). setUp() and tearDown() are empty, i did not remove them but they're in the original script empty too.

Comment: I see the output of my script in the terminal and there i don't get any errors. When i set  error_reporting(E_ALL); and ini_set('display_errors', '1'); there are still no errors.

Comment: By the way, I have to say that the same script works online on the production server. Only on my local server I have this problem.

Comment: It seems there is an issue with regular expressions. The function preg_replace isn't working too but str_replace with replacement of a normal string is working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that it is working now. I didn't find the problem, but after the update to  macOS Big Sur it seems to work now.